# Delete does not work in only Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, forms, internet-explorer

So this code works in every browser except Internet Explorer. How can I make it work in IE?

//html code

```
<form action="postdel.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Confirm: DELETE <?php echo $productname; ?>?');">

<input type="hidden" value="delete" title='Delete Item'> 
 <button style='height:33px; width:50px'>
      <img src="../css/images/delete_25.png" />
 </button>
</form>
```

//postdel.php

```
ob_start();
include("../conn.php");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM specials WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

header('Location: foo.php');
```

`$id` is just a random number.  I'm assuming the problem is with the JavaScript popup to confirm the delete.  Because when you press OK, it accepts, removes the dialog and sits back on the same page. All other browsers, it confirms, and goes to the foo page.

Comment: So the form submits, and the delete is happening, but the `header()` redirect isn't working in IE, or doesn't it submit the form in IE, or what exactly is happening ?

Comment: read the bottom, I explained it. It does not Delete the item's MySQL listing, it does nothing other than remove the confirm delete dialog

Comment: @rockethazmat, I've only confirmed it on IE10

Comment: IE doesn't accept relative URL's in `header()`, you'll need an absolute URL, and I'm trying to ask if the `header()` redirect is the real problem, as you didn't really explain it very well.

Comment: I agree with @adeneo, try using an absolute path, like: `header('Location: /foo.php');` (or wherever it's located).

Comment: Also, using a hidden input with the name `id` and the value from PHP's `$id` seems more proper than a querystring and will ensure that the form is submitted with the proper values, as right now you're POST'ing a form with GET values.

Comment: @adeneo: While strange, you *can* POST a form to a URL with a query string (GET values) on it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Yeah, I know it works, just seems like a bad idea and not the intended use. Why use POST to get `$_GET` values ?

Comment: I did /foo.php, nothing. I don't know how to explain this in anymore detail, it does nothing, when you enter foo.php its supposed to do 2 things, delete the listing, and redirect, it doesn't do either. redirecting is the least of my worries at this point, it's purpose of deleting the database listing is the priority.

Comment: If you just remove the confirm and do nothing onsubmit, does the form submit in IE

Comment: guys, if there anything you want me to change in my code, im 100% willing, i'm not an expert coder. if something is not the standard or looks right, let me know, ill change it, I don't care at this point

Comment: @adeneo, no it doesn't do anything after I removed the confirm, nice catch.

Comment: all I want to do is to do is take this ID, delete it from the MySQL field and redirect

Comment: Then add something to the form, right now there doesn't seem to be anything to submit, not that it should matter, but add names and values, as in `<input name="name" value="something" />` and see if the form submits then.

Comment: are you talking about in my hidden input? because you have to remember this is a button. I add this `<input type="hidden" value="delete" title='Delete Item' name="delete">`, nothing

Comment: Nope, just add an extra input and see if the form submits, there has to be something strange going on if the form never reaches the server, you just have to try stuff until you figure out what ?

Comment: does anyone have a suggestion on how I would delete this field using only a button that has an id attached to itself when submitting? because I'm about ready to scrap this code all together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyway, I don't know why this isn't working. I just did this as my solution, hopefully it will help someone else.

I just basically got rid of the form all together and just used the button to execute the delete command.

//html

```
<button onclick="location.href='postdel.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>'" style='height:33px; width:50px;'><img src="../css/images/delete_25.png" border="0"/></button>
```

//php

```
ob_start();
include("../conn.php");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM specials WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

header('Location: foo.php');
```

Comment: The reason this works probably is because IE was caching your page and it kept the same URL so it rendered the same page. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving the form a name using the name attribute, which is applied to the form:

```
name="deleteform"
```

would render the following:

```
form action="postdel.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Confirm: DELETE <?php echo $productname; ?>?');" name="deleteform">
```

Comment: And this will somehow fix the problem?

Comment: I think that IE might need it in order to actually sumbit the form, but I might be wrong.